# C# JSON Deserialize Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> optional?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

My payload would look something like this:

```
{
    "REFERENCE": "1",
    "FIELDS" : {
        "CUST" : "1234",
        "PROD" : "PR2134",
        "LIMIT" : "12345",
        "LINES" : {
              "LINE" : "01",
              "DATA" : "12"
        }
    }
}
```

My object simply has the following:

```
public class TriggerRequest
{
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> fields { get; set; }

}
```

Obviously, this doesn't handle the LINES object. How can I create a class that deserializes an inbound payload where something like LINES is dynamic (i.e. I can send in any Dictionary> at any point in the payload and it'll deserialize correctly. Is this something when I need to create a custom JsonConverter?

Comment: It's because it's case sensitive..

Comment: Before starting to roll your own JSON converter you should look into some of the packages already available including JSON.net and Silverlight's `System.Json` Most of them have the ability to deserialize to dynamic or to `Dictionary<string, object>`

Comment: `JObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeJson(string json)` from the `Newtonsoft.Json` library (AKA Json.net)  would probably work well for what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `dynamic` instead.

```
public class TriggerRequest
{
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public dynamic fields { get; set; }
}
```

This should allow you to access `(string)request.fields.lines.data` directly in your code, for example.

However, if you don't know at compile time what values will be in there, you may prefer to make fields a `JObject`.

```
public class TriggerRequest
{
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public JObject fields { get; set; }
}
```

This gives you the opportunity to write code that inspects what kind of data is in each of its properties and respond accordingly.

Finally, if you *do* know what properties you expect `fields` to have, create a separate class for it.

```
public class TriggerRequest
{
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public TriggerRequestFields fields { get; set; }
}

public class TriggerRequestFields
{
    public string cust {get;set;}
    ...
    public TriggerRequestLines lines {get;set;}
}

public class TriggerRequestLines
{
    public string line {get;set;}
    public string data {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
public Dictionary<string, dynamic> fields { get; set; }
```

With

```
public Dictionary<string, object> fields { get; set; }
```